# Authenticator evaluates the request and responds by sending notifications over fidoStatus characteristic

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, authenticator, cbor

I am making a mobile authenticator which supports CTAP BLE to communicate with WebAuthn.
I follow this document: https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-id-20180227/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-id-20180227.html#ble-protocol-overview

The Protocol Overview as following:

1. Authenticator advertises the FIDO Service.
2. Client scans for authenticator advertising the FIDO Service.
3. Client performs characteristic discovery on the authenticator.
4. If not already paired, the client, and authenticator SHALL perform BLE pairing and create an LTK. Authenticator SHALL only allow connections from previously bonded clients without user intervention.
5. Client checks if the fidoServiceRevisionBitfield characteristic is present. If so, the client selects a supported version by writing a value with a single bit set.
6. Client reads the fidoControlPointLength characteristic.
7. Client registers for notifications on the fidoStatus characteristic.
8. Client writes a request (e.g. an enroll request) into the fidoControlPoint characteristic.
9. Optionally, the client writes a CANCEL command to the fidoControlPoint characteristic to cancel the pending request.
10. Authenticator evaluates the request and responds by sending notifications over fidoStatus characteristic.
11. The protocol completes when either:

    - The client unregisters for notifications on the fidoStatus characteristic, or:
    - The connection times out and is closed by the authenticator.

At step 8, I receive the message like this: **0x83000700030000000000**, I understand that

0x83 is MSG command

0x0007 is length of data

00030000000000 is data

When I receive such a message, I don't know what to response to WebAuthn as step 10 says "Authenticator evaluates the request and responds by sending notifications over fidoStatus characteristic."

Comment: Hi Bao, I am trying the same authenticator in Android. I can able to read sample characteristics but i couldn't able read Fido characteristics. 
1) I have created fidoControlPoint, fidoStatus, fidoControlPointLength characteristics, etc with their corresponding UUID. 
2) Then I have added all those characteristics with fido service.
onCharacteristicReadRequest() is not getting called for Fido service. But onCharacteristicReadRequest() is getting called for sample service. 

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mine is working fine.You should show me the code then I can help to check.

Comment: fidoControlPointLength.setValue(new byte[] {(byte) 0x1F4});

fidoServiceRevisionBitfield.setValue(new byte[] {(byte) 0x19});

fidoControlPointLength.setValue(new byte[] {(byte) 0x19});

fidoService.addCharacteristic(fidoControlPoint);
fidoService.addCharacteristic(fidoStatus);
fidoService.addCharacteristic(fidoControlPointLength);
fidoService.addCharacteristic(fidoServiceRevisionBitfield);
fidoService.addCharacteristic(fidoServiceRevision);  This is how I initiated my fidoU2F service. I can get fidoControlPointLen characteristic in onCharacteristicReadRequest() method. Is this right?

Comment: I think your case is implementation problem, please refer this source to debug your app. https://github.com/freeu2f/freeu2f-android. This is U2F, not FIDO2, but it is good enough to help you on BLE problem. Sorry I can not share my source because of company policy.

Comment: Thank you very very much Bao.. It helped me a lot.

Comment: I am stuck with step 5. I receive fidoServiceRevisionBitfield characteristic in onCharacteristicReadRequest(). I am not getting any callback further. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time of checking, I found the answer. The reason is I am interacting with WebAuthn on Android Chrome which supports CTAP1/U2F. Now it's working fine when I work with Chrome (ver 75) on Desktop which support CTAP2.

The point to recognize WebAuthn supports CTAP2 is AuthenticatorGetInfo sent to authenticator. It is 0x83000104

0x83 is MSG command

0x0001 is length of content

04 is AuthenticatorGetInfo

[image]